# React - reduce strange interaction on input setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `quiz` and it has an arr of `questions`, a `question` has value.

I want to assign the total of `questions` `question.value` to the `quiz.value` as the value updates.

Here is how i am currently handling the updating (obviously i havent dealt with if a question is removed yet)

```
const handleUpdateQuestionScore = (e) => {
    setQuiz({...quiz, questions: quiz.questions.map((child, index) => index === selectedQuestion ? { ...child, value: parseInt(e.target.value) } : child)})
    setReUpdateTotal(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => { // this has weird behaviour
    console.log("my total", quiz.questions.reduce((total, question) => total = total + question.value, 0))
    if(quiz.questions.length < 1) {
      setQuiz({ ...quiz, value: 0  } )
    }
    else{
      setQuiz({...quiz, value: quiz.questions.reduce((total, question) => total = total + question.value, 0) } )
    }
  },[reUpdateTotal])
```

The issue with this is, when i set question 1, its correct.
When i add question 2 and set its value, sometimes it only interpolates the first number.
going back off the form and loading it up will update.

Other times it will not update the value at all.

For a much more indept demonstration, this codeSandbox demonstrates functionality:
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-shadow-i9z2wx?file=/src/App.js

Here is the default code in the codeSandbox

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
    title: "",
    number: 6,
    questions: [
      {
        question: "q1",
        value: 0
      },
      {
        question: "q2",
        value: 0
      }
    ]
  });
  const [selectedQuestion, setSelectedQuestion] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("quiz", quiz);
  }, [quiz]);

  const [reUpdateTotal, setReUpdateTotal] = useState();

  const handleUpdateQuestionScore = (e) => {
    setQuiz({
      ...quiz,
      questions: quiz.questions.map((child, index) =>
        index === selectedQuestion
          ? { ...child, value: parseInt(e.target.value) }
          : child
      )
    });
    setReUpdateTotal(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // this has weird behaviour
    console.log(
      "my total",
      quiz.questions.reduce(
        (total, question) => (total = total + question.value),
        0
      )
    );
    if (quiz.questions.length < 1) {
      setQuiz({ ...quiz, value: 0 });
    } else {
      setQuiz({
        ...quiz,
        value: quiz.questions.reduce(
          (total, question) => (total = total + question.value),
          0
        )
      });
    }
  }, [reUpdateTotal]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {quiz.questions.map((question, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>
              {question.question} - {question.value}
              <button onClick={() => setSelectedQuestion(index)}>select</button>
            </p>

            <br />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <br />
      <small>change value for question #{selectedQuestion}</small>
      {selectedQuestion !== undefined ? (
        <div>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="Value"
            name="Value"
            required="required"
            className="edit-input shadow"
            min="0"
            value={quiz.questions[selectedQuestion].value}
            onChange={(e) => {
              handleUpdateQuestionScore(e);
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedQuestion(undefined)}>remove</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>nothing selected</div>
      )}

      <h1>current total score = {quiz.value}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically - your useEffect that has a `[reUpdateTotal]` as a dependency array executes only once. When switching value from `false` to `true`. Im not seeing where you are switching it back. But still, you dont even need this variable and rely on the useEffect with `[quiz]` which will execute only 1 function - `setQuiz`. And no, it will not cause infinite rerenderings, if used correctly. It can accept a function with 1 parameter, which will be your "current" value of a `quiz`. I used `prev` but actually it is `curr`. And this function can return either a new value and fire a rerender, either the current value and do nothing in this case.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
    title: "",
    number: 6,
    questions: [
      { question: "q1", value: 0 },
      { question: "q2", value: 0 }
    ]
  });
  const [selectedQuestionIndex, setSelectedQuestionIndex] = useState(undefined);

  const handleUpdateQuestionScore = (e) => {
    setQuiz((prev) => {
      prev.questions[selectedQuestionIndex].value = parseInt(
        e.target.value,
        10
      );
      return { ...prev };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setQuiz((prev) => {
      const currValue = prev.value;
      const newValue =
        prev.questions?.reduce(
          (total, question) => (total = total + question.value),
          0
        ) || 0;
      if (newValue === currValue) return prev;
      return {
        ...prev,
        value: newValue
      };
    });
  }, [quiz]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {quiz.questions?.map((question, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>
              {question.question} - {question.value}
              <button onClick={() => setSelectedQuestionIndex(index)}>
                select
              </button>
            </p>

            <br />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <br />
      <small>change value for question #{selectedQuestionIndex}</small>
      {selectedQuestionIndex !== undefined ? (
        <div>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="Value"
            name="Value"
            required="required"
            className="edit-input shadow"
            min="0"
            value={quiz.questions[selectedQuestionIndex].value}
            onChange={handleUpdateQuestionScore}
          />
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedQuestionIndex(undefined)}>
            remove
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>nothing selected</div>
      )}

      <h1>current total score = {quiz.value}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a bit more clear way of handling "quiz.value" using `useMemo`:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
    title: "",
    number: 6,
    questions: [
      { question: "q1", value: 0 },
      { question: "q2", value: 0 }
    ]
  });
  const [selectedQuestionIndex, setSelectedQuestionIndex] = useState(undefined);
  const selectedQuestion = useMemo(() => {
    if (!quiz?.questions || selectedQuestionIndex === undefined)
      return undefined;
    return quiz.questions[selectedQuestionIndex];
  }, [quiz, selectedQuestionIndex]);

  const quizTotalValue = useMemo(() => {
    if (!quiz || !quiz.questions) return 0;
    return quiz.questions.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.value, 0);
  }, [quiz]);

  const handleUpdateQuestionScore = (e) => {
    if (!selectedQuestion) return;
    selectedQuestion.value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
    setQuiz((prev) => ({ ...prev }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {quiz.questions?.map((question, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <p>
              {question.question} - {question.value}
              <button onClick={() => setSelectedQuestionIndex(index)}>
                select
              </button>
            </p>

            <br />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <br />
      <small>change value for question #{selectedQuestionIndex}</small>
      {selectedQuestion !== undefined ? (
        <div>
          <input
            type="number"
            id="Value"
            name="Value"
            required="required"
            className="edit-input shadow"
            min="0"
            value={selectedQuestion.value}
            onChange={handleUpdateQuestionScore}
          />
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedQuestionIndex(undefined)}>
            remove
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>nothing selected</div>
      )}

      <h1>current total score = {quizTotalValue}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ah yea your explanation makes sense as to why it wasnt working, your solution seem more polished and I do appreciate the suggested change from `selectedQuestion` to `selectedQuestionIndex` for clarity.  :)

Comment: @ABpositive Can I ask about why do you want to store "value" inside of the "quiz" object? Im curious because there is a bit more efficient and clear/obvious way to achieve that value without tricks like i used here, using `useMemo` hook, but this value can only be outside of this "quiz" object. I can show how to do that if you want.

Comment: NP, for context: in my app, viewing a quiz before participation it shows score (estimated difficulty). After completing a quiz, the account is given score based on questions  correct as a grade. 

Originally a quiz score was separate from question values. But for streamlining purposes it makes more sense to be based questions value. 

If you want to show a more efficient example feel free, though the example you provided is great otherwise!  @Sergey Sosunov

Comment: @ABpositive Added an example, curious which one looks better for you. I mean both of them will work and both of them are correct but as for me - it is better to have a useMemo to compute values to display (and not only, as you can see with "selectedQuestion") instead of modification of the original data objects